# Input defaultValue from other component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

**Code**

I am trying to pull values from other Component( Barcode Scanner ).
Its show the correct value in console, how can I populate the value in input field in `ReactJS`

**Component1**

```
  <Redirect
    to={{
      pathname: "/users",
      state: { barcode: this.state.barcode },
    }}
  />
```

**component2**

```
  state = {
    barcode: "Nothing",
    name: "",
    phone: "",
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.location.state);
    if (this.props.location.state) {
      this.setState({ barcode: this.props.location.state });
    }
  }

<input
   type="text"
   defaultValue={this.state.barcode}
/>
```

`console.log(this.props.location.state)` shows the following.
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by `pull values from other Component` ? is it parent-child hierarchy or what ?

Comment: @shubhamjha, there are 2 components, in `component1` its just scan the code and redirect to `component2` with state. and In `component2` I just need that state value in field. **check my Question**

Comment: is there a call back within component1? For example, the next react component uses call backs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-barcode-reader

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga, yes, I get the barcode and its redirect to other component and there is form which need to autofill with that barcode. I am facing issue ( lack of knowledge ) how to place value of barcode in input field.

Comment: Within the `render()`, can you `console.log(this.state.barcode)`? What you get in there?

Comment: I know, this is not best solution but just pass value directly in state `state = {
    barcode: this.props.location.state.barcode,
    name: "",
    phone: "",
  };`

Comment: tried this approach ?                                                                   
` this.setState((prevState)=> ({ ...prevState, barcode: this.props.location.state }));`

Comment: The callbacks allows the "easy" transfer of data between components.